# Arrange $16$ bit binary digits into a circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

How to arrange $16$ binary digits into a circle, such that the $16$ 4-bit binary numbers will only be present once?

Comment: What have you tried? What about an easier problem? Can you solve it with $8$ binary digits so that all $8$ three-bit words are present once each? Or how about $4$ bits so that all two-bit words are present?

Comment: You seem to be referring to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence $B(2,4)$.  `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1`

Comment: thanks, the link was really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directed graph where the nodes are all of the 3-bit binary numbers and an arc goes from a vertex labeled $abc$ to a vertex labeled $xyz$ if $b=x$ and $c=y$.  Label that arc $z$.

[image]

This directed graph is strongly connected and every node in this directed graph has the same indegree and outdegree. Therefore, there is a directed Euler circuit in this directed graph. Every such circuit corresponds to a De Bruijn sequence in a pretty obvious way.

Comment: This digraph is called a De Bruijn graph.